# Convert a Static Library to a Shared Library?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a third-party library which consists mainly of a large number of static (`.a`) library files.  I can compile this into a single `.a` library file, but I really need it to be a single `.so` shared library file.

Is there any way to convert a static `.a` file into a shared `.so` file?  Or more generally is there a good way to combine a huge number of static `.a` files with a few `.o` object files into a single `.so` file?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Does this (with appropriate -L's of course)

```
gcc -shared -o megalib.so foo.o bar.o -la_static_lib -lb_static_lib
```

Not do it?

Comment: Using gcc -shared did the trick, but only after I recompiled with -fPIC.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I know this is an old answert but it... doesn't work? With every static library I have tried this the resulting shared object does not export any of the original symbols anymore.

Comment: I encountered the same issue @Peter

Comment: @Peter: I'm guessing you're not using any `.o` files at all, and just trying to directly convert from static lib to dynamic lib providing all the same symbols. If so, there's [a trick to telling the linker to include all the unused names from the archive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7935421/364696) you'll need to use.

Answer (score 30):

You can't do this if objects within static library was compiled without -fPIC or like.

Comment: On well-supported targets, `PIC` is not essential for shared library code. It just results in much more efficient use of memory (the majority, instead of a minority, of pages can be shared) at the expense of some performance.

Comment: Missing of -fPIC or like at some conditions result in SegFault

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I belive you, but source? :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com: That comment is from 12 years ago and probably reflected the state of things at the time, but now it's pretty much outdated. The modern consensus is that TEXTREL support is a legacy feature that modern targets aren't really expected to support well or even at all, and indeed many don't.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE no-PIC code still is faster on all major platforms, because of better use of cache

Comment: @vitaly.v.ch: That's not the topic at hand, and no, it's not even true - modern architectures have completely-free PC-relative addressing. But the topic was whether non-PIC code in shared libraries is supported, and nowadays, the answer is "no, except when it is" (i.e. not in general).

Answer (score 20):

```
g++ -shared -o megalib.so foo.o bar.o -Wl,--whole-archive -la_static_lib -lb_static_lib -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lc_static_lib -lother_shared_object
```

I'm not sure about gcc, but for g++ I had to add the --whole-archive linker option to include the objects from the static libraries in the shared object.
The --no-whole-archive option is necessary if you want to link to libc_static_lib.a and libother_shared_object.so, but not include them as a whole in megalib.so.

Comment: `-Wl--no-whole-archive` is necessary at the end of the command line. See [the question edit, here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935421/linking-archives-a-into-shared-object-so).

Answer (score 13):

`ar -x` can be also useful if you want to focus on specific objects from your `.a`s and you don't want to add anything on your own.

Examples:

```
ar -x lib***.a
gcc -shared *.o -o lib***.so
```

Comment: `ar -x` doesn't support unpacking a list of archives, so `ar -x lib1.a lib2.a ...` will print `no entry lib2.a in archive`. The solution is to : `mk extracted; parallel ar --output extracted -x ::: *.a` and then run `gcc` in `extracted`

Answer (score 7):

```
ar -x lib***.a
gcc -shared *.o -o lib***.so
```

Comment: Wasn't this just taken from another earlier answer, and posted with less context / explanation?

Comment: No, there was not such answer by that time. See history.

Comment: I could've sworn in the web browser it showed the date for the other one was earlier, but in the phone app it's showing this one was first.  My apologies!