# shared library under ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, pinvoke, single-responsibility-principle

i have compiled srp-2.1.2 under ubuntu using make ,it creat a file libsrp.a. can any one tell me how can i use libsrp.a as shared library?.i want to use libsrp in a c# file under ubuntu by using dllimport.please tell me what is the meaning of libsrp.a file.

thanks

ok when i am using nm -D libsrp.a 
then i have

c2@ubuntu:~/Desktop/srp-2.1.2/libsrp$ nm -D libsrp.a

t_client.o:
nm: t_client.o: No symbols

please tell me how i will get all symbols.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `libsrp.a` file is a static library; a shared library would be called something like `libsrp.so`.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193944/convert-a-static-library-to-a-shared-library-create-libsome-so-from-libsome-a) there's an answer that describes a way to to build a shared library from a static library (I've never done this myself though, so can't vouch that it works - good luck!)

UPDATE:

Using `nm` with the `-D` argument asks for dynamic symbols (check out `man nm`) - in the question I linked to the guy was using `-D` as he was invoking `nm` on a *shared library*.  Your `libsrp.a` is a static library, so to see the symbols you should just do

```
nm libsrp.a
```

However, I don't think you should need to see the symbols to make use of the answer explaining how to get a shared library; if the answer is correct, you should just have to invoke `gcc` with the correct arguments.  I guess once you've got the shared library you could use `nm` to see if it has the symbols you expect; in that case you *will* need the `-D` argument:

```
nm -D libsrp.so
```