# In compiling C++, how to make a .a file to .so?

Tags: c++, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a Static Library to a Shared Library (create libsome.so from libsome.a): where’s my symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193944/convert-a-static-library-to-a-shared-library-create-libsome-so-from-libsome-a)

In compiling C++ with Cmakefile, how can I create a dynamic library .so file out of .a static library file?

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building the library, you are using CMake (as I guess from your question), and it is defined like this:

```
add_library(name-of-library
    source1.cpp
    source2.cpp
)
```

You can add the type of library you want to build after the name of the library. It can be `STATIC` or `SHARED`. So if you want to build a shared library (`.so`), then the above should be transformed like this:

```
add_library(name-of-library SHARED
    source1.cpp
    source2.cpp
)
```

Hope this helps.