# Dynamic library do not have symbol of static library file

Tags: c++, c, gcc

There are no symbols of static library files or functins in a dynamic library(.so) file.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and 12.04 system.
I created an object file from cpp file with -fPIC option than the created static library (.a).
After that I created a dynamic library using a command :g++ -shared -I(include path) -L(other library path) -l(librarys) -o filename.so -Wl,-soname,filename.so staticlib.a"
I show symbol created in 12.04 ubuntu system but not in 18.04 system.
I show so file created by there no symbols in so file. we can check it using nm -g filename .so.

I got this type of result in nm command in 18.04 system if I try with 12.04 it give me whole sysmbols of all cpp files.

```
$ nm -g libPJ.so
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000201020 B __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000201020 D _edata
0000000000201028 B _end
000000000000052c T _fini
0000000000000410 T _init
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Keep all exported symbols when creating a shared library from a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664759/keep-all-exported-symbols-when-creating-a-shared-library-from-a-static-library)

Comment: I suspect you are using gcc, please add it to the tags, since this is no general c question

Comment: @Raidri thank this link works for me. I need to use -Wl,--whole-archive and -Wl,--no-whole-archive before and after static lib.

Answer (score 0):

When linking a shared library from a static library add `-Wl,-whole-archive` linker flag. From [`man ld`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html):

> ```
>   --whole-archive
>        For each archive mentioned on the command line after the
>        --whole-archive option, include every object file in the archive in
>        the link, rather than searching the archive for the required object
>        files.  This is normally used to turn an archive file into a shared
>        library, forcing every object to be included in the resulting
>        shared library.  This option may be used more than once.
>
>      Two notes when using this option from gcc: First, gcc doesn’t know
>        about this option, so you have to use -Wl,-whole-archive.  Second,
>        don’t forget to use -Wl,-no-whole-archive after your list of
>        archives, because gcc will add its own list of archives to your
>        link and you may not want this flag to affect those as well.
> ```

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks.