# how to make shared library from a static library under ubuntu using gcc

Tags: ubuntu, shared-libraries

i have a static library libsrp.a, i want to make a shared library libsrp.so from it that contains all symbols . please tell me how to make a .so under ubuntu.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655163/convert-a-static-library-to-a-shared-library

Answer (score 3):

Recompile the object files contained in libsrp.a with the flag to create position independent code (fpic) as in

```
gcc -fpic -c foo.c
gcc -fpic -c bar.c
```

Now you can combine foo.o and bar.o into a shared library as in

```
gcc -shared -o libshared.so foo.o bar.o
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--whole-archive` flag:

```
gcc -shared -o libsrp.so -Wl,--whole-archive -lsrp -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

From the [ld man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) (my emphasis):

> --whole-archive
>       For each archive mentioned on the command line after the --whole-archive option, include every object file in the archive in the link, rather than searching the archive for the required object files. **This is normally used to turn an archive file into a shared library, forcing every object to be included in the resulting shared library.** This option may be used more than once.

Comment: If the original .a file contains object files which are compiled without fPIC, can the newly generated corresponding .so file work properly?

Comment: @solotim - I've been successfully able to use non PIC code in shared objects on 32 bit Linux - although it looks like that may not be the case for 64 bit Linux.