# Linking archives (.a) into shared object (.so)

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I'm compiling some shared objects file into an `archive.a`:

```
$ g++ -c -Iinclude/ -fPIC -O0 -o object1.o source1.cpp
$ g++ -c -Iinclude/ -fPIC -O0 -o object2.o source2.cpp
$ ar rvs archive.a object1.o object2.o
r - object1.o
r - object2.o
```

So far so good. The resulting `archive.a` has a good size of some KB. A dump with `nm` shows that the corresponding object-files are contained within the files.

Now I'm wanting to compile several of these archives into a shared object file.

```
g++ -g -O0 -Iinclude/ -I/usr/include/somelibrary -shared -o libLibrary.so archive1.a archive2.a
```

The result is that my resulting library file is nearly **empty**:

```
$ nm -D libLibrary.so
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000201010 A __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000201010 A _edata
0000000000201020 A _end
0000000000000578 T _fini
0000000000000430 T _init
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Edit:**

When I try the switch `-Wl,--whole-archive`, following happens:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `__init_array_end' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libKeynect.so] Error 1
```

Comment: I meet a similar error of undefined symbol. For myself, ld option '-Bsymblic' causes the issue. Remove '-Bsymblic' solved the issue. Maybe you could try ld option '-Bdynamic'.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

symbols/object files  in .a files that's not used, will be discarded by the linker.

Use `-Wl,--whole-archive` for the linking to include the entire .a file
Edit, you'll need to add `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` after you specify your library as well, so the whole thing will be `-Wl,--whole-archive archive1.a archive2.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive`

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Unfortunately, I seem to run in another problem. I modified the question.

Answer (score 9):

Regarding your edit:  Put "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" at the end of the link command you're running.  That fixed it for me.