# Call into static C library from Python

Tags: python, c, static-libraries

I have a static C library, that I need to call into from Python. I was looking at ctypes for this however it can only work with dynamically loaded libraries. Is there an equivalent or alternative for staticly linked libraries?

Comment: A static lib on its own is almost useless. It's supposed to be linked into an *ELF* (or *PE* on *Win*).

Answer (score 3):

You can't; static libraries are for linking to make new executables or dynamic libraries and nothing else. But you may be able to [create a dynamic library from a static one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/655163/364696) ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7935421/364696)), depending on how the static library was compiled.

Comment: They could do it by building CPython with the static-library-using extension as a built-in, I believe.  But I'm inclined to guess that they are not prepared to go that far.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes, they could make an actual Python extension by whatever means are appropriate; my answer was the minimal work answer to "make a static library usable from Python", but the broad answer is "it needs to be something other than a static library" to be usable, where converting to a dynamic library is one of many options (none of which load the static library in its original form).

Answer (score 0):

One option I've used to do this is to execute a python script from within a C\C++ application.  The Boost.Python implementation is what I used to accomplish this.  I statically linked the library file to the C app and ran the python script from the app. The methods in the C app that call into your static C library can be exposed to the python script.

Although the above is a solution...another way to do it is to build a pipe client in python, then connect to a C app (that is running a pipe server) that is statically linked to your library.